# TikZ/pgf: How can I define new edges for use with the `graphdrawing` library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Apart from the standard `->`, `<-`, `--` or `<->`, how can I define new edges for use with the `graphdrawing` library?

Here are some kinds of new edges I am interested in:

"Flatheads:"

```
|----------------------------

----------------------------|

|---------------------------|
```

"Half-heads":

```
________________________________\

________________________________
\
```

Someone mentioned that `-|` is already defined, but using it in `graphdrawing` gives me an error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}

\begin{document}

\tikz [rounded corners]
    \graph [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
    {
        a -| {
            b,
            c -> { d, e }
        } ->
        f ->
        a
    };

\end{document}

Package tikz Error: One of the arrow types <-, --, ->, -!- or <-> expected }
```

How can I go about setting up new edges for use with `graphdrawing`? Do teach me how to fish, rather than only give me a fish, if you have the time and energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give options to arrow specifications

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners]
    \graph [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
    {
        a -!- {
            b,
            c ->[>=|] { d, e }
        } ->
        f ->[>=Hooks]
        a
    };
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where should I looked in `pgfmanual.pdf` in order to find out what `>=|` means?

Comment: @user89 Page 267 for version 3.00. There you can define new edges which is precisely what you are looking for

Comment: Why does `<->[<->={|}{>}{decoration={snake}}]` do nothing? Or, in other words, where in `pgfmanual.pdf` do I have to look what possibilities exist for *`edge options`*?

Comment: `<->[<->={|}{>}{decorate, decoration={snake}}]` does nothing either...doesn't even throw up an error!